# asp .net multiple validators for one control

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am developing asp.net web site. I have a from on a page and have text boxes. I am using `Validators` to validate fields. I used two validators to validate my telephone number field. One to check **length** and other to check **All entered value are numbers**

My issue is: for a invalid input which does not match above two conditions, bot the error messages are displaying.

I would like to display only 1 error message at a time. Is this possible? Please advice me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was manage to fix my issue. using **CSS**

**This is how I did**

wrote a new css class(.errorMsg) in style sheet to handle the display style of error messages.

Assign that css class to each validator.

Now multiple error messages for invalid input is overlapped.

To fix it, I assigned background color for the error message `<span>`  tag. (Background color is same as forms BbColor).

So now overlapped messages are not showing.  only the topmost error is showing now.

Answer (score 1):

"The ValidationSummary server control works with all the validation server controls on the page. It takes all the error messages that the other validation controls send back to the page and puts them all in one spot (that you specify) on the page. These error messages can be displayed in a list, bulleted list, or paragraph."

Use ValidationSummary Control.

EDIT: Now I see what you want, you need the Custom Validator control. Watch this example:

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

In there you will learn about the IsValid property which let's you determine When the input expression is actually valid. A couple of if-else will do the work.

Comment: By using that, it is possible to display the error message in front of the per field. Not a single place for every error message on all the controls?

Comment: oops!, sorry. In your case then you should try the Custom Validator control. Look at this example: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

With that as a base you may do what you want

Answer (score -1):

I think you need only one validator,beacause you can restrict the length of input character by setting the maxlength property of textbox control.ie you need only a regular expression validator to validating numbers.But if you still need to include two validators  and display one message you can write javascript for validation.